# Cannot install afpfs-ng

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, xubuntu, afp

On Xubuntu 16.04LTS amd64, I cannot install afpfs-ng. This is a HUGE problem for me since my school uses macs and an afp file server, and I only have a PC running Linux and I need a file for the summer. When I try through the software center (both i386 AND amd64), it simply does not work. The install button literally does nothing. Through the command line (sudo apt-get install afpfs-ng) I get that the package has no installation candidate.

Comment: 'afpfs-ng' packages, example https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/afpfs-ng/0.8.1-5ubuntu1/+build/5380631 .. Ref. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/afpfs-ng -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Ubuntu 16.04, afpfs-ng :

```
sudo apt-get install g++ libfuse-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev git

git clone https://github.com/simonvetter/afpfs-ng
cd afpfs-ng/
./configure && make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the tar.gz file direct from SourceForge page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/

And extract:

```
tar jxf afpfs-ng-0.8.1.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
apt-get install g++ libfuse-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev git
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ libfuse-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev git

git clone https://github.com/simonvetter/afpfs-ng
cd afpfs-ng/
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu got rid of `afpfs-ng`. You may use `afpfs-ng` package from another disto. I put deb-package from ArchLinux into Github repo https://github.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb

So you may use it something like this:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb/main/afpfs-ng.deb
sudo apt install ./afpfs-ng.deb
sudo mkdir -p /media/airport
sudo mount_afp afp://myuser:mypass@mycapsule/Data /media/airport
sudo ls /media/airport
sudo umount /media/airport
```